# JButton inside JMenuItem

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jmenu, jmenuitem

I'm trying to build a particular `JMenu`.
I want a `JMenuItem` with `JMenu` functionality, I.E. when we click it the item should do something (like opening a dialog). But the `JMenuItem` should also contain a button (or other component) that when we click it, should open a popup with a couple of options.

So, till now I have something like this:

[image: Desired UI]

That is what I have before click the arrow.

My problem is that, when I press the button (arrow), the sub-menu is actually opened, but the menu item that contains that button closes because loses focus.

[image: Broken UI]

That is the result after clicking in the arrow button.

Is there any way to manage this? Or a better way to have this behavior?

Comment: So you want one menu item (one line in the menu) to have two different behaviors - perform some action when clicking on the text and open a submenu when clicking on the button? That would not be very userfriendly, better use a menugroup for the submenu, i.e. ad a new (sub) `JMenu`.

Comment: my question, why did you put JButton in the JMenu as JMenuItem, are you not satisfied with the basic implementations

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, that's exactly what I want: perform an action when click in the text and open the popup when click the button.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced this is something you *should* do.  Having said that:  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: `JButton m = new JButton();`
    
`JMenuBar abc = (JMenuBar) new JMenuBar().add(m);`
How about something like this?

Comment: So, I spent some time looking at this and I realized that the MenuItem with the arrow button closes because a new popup is opened and not related with the first.
I solved this problem just adding a button that toggle between the option 1 and option 2 and in that case I avoid the second popup and all the problems related with it.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't actually find a solution for this particular problem.
As a workaround, I used just a simple button that toggle between the option 1 and option 2, instead of having the button (arrow) that open a new popup.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

We can guide you if we know exactly what you are trying to implement. If you just want to select an option, you can implement that in better way with the `JRadioButtonMenuItem`,so you dont really need to implement a button and then select an option.But it depends on what you really want.

Comment: I want exactly what Thomas mentioned. I know it's not user friendly, but at this moment that's how I should try to do it.

Answer (score 2):

That's not what a menu is intended for. Use a [ribbon](http://blog.frankel.ch/flamingo-tutorial) instead, and these things will be easy and natural.

Comment: I agree, using a menu like that would be quite counter-intuitive. Ribbons seem like the way better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use simple nested `JMenuItem` instead? 
Something like [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) (First screen from the top).

On the other hand you can benefit from a similar solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972368/custom-jmenuitems-in-java).