# JMenuItem delete "X" to the right of the text

Tags: java, swing

I have a JMenuItem which I would like to be able to remove from the menu.

```
[ ] The Item      X
[x] Selected Item X
```

I currently have the menu created with radio buttons so that as each item is selected, the others are deselected.

I would like the "X" to the right of the menu, to remove the item from the menu itself.

Comment: Is this just a yes/no question?

Comment: Are you trying to create this menu layout, or remove something from it? Your question isn't clear.

Comment: Updated. Is that clearer?

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972368/custom-jmenuitems-in-java) will give you ideas.